# How to split an string type array by value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I got an array of `str`:

```
['12.5', '7', '45', '\n', '13.7', '52', '34.3', '\n']
```

And I want to split it by value, in this case by `'\n'`, so it becomes:

```
[['12.5',  '7', '45'],
 ['13.7', '52', '34.3']]
```

I don't want to enumerate every element since it's time consuming when input has a large scale. So I wonder if there are some functions or python tricks that can easily achieve this.

P.S.

I've saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274243/split-array-at-value-in-numpy) but it doesn't help much. Mainly because I don't quite understand how `np.where()` works with `np.split()`, also because I'm working on `str` type.

Another thing might be helpful is that my final goal is to generate a matrix of numbers (maybe `float` type), so I'll also be glad to know if there's any numpy function can do this.

Comment: Even if you don't want to use a loop to iterate through your elements and you prefer using "some functions or python tricks that can easily achieve this", these tools you are looking for **will** use a loop. So why not use one yourself for such a basic operation ?

Comment: @IMCoins I learned from some courses that many packages are using GPU computing matrices, which is faster than implement by myself with some explicit `for` loop.

Comment: @AmarthGûl Unfortunately, most of the packages that do that are 3rd party packages, and a loop is usually your best bet because it is implemented in C.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Well, when implementing matrix computations, I found `numpy` functions are way more faster than operations written by myself. So I was actually hoping `numpy` could save me again. Now seems you're right, the answers below are still using `for` loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) which, of course, does iterate the list, but is highly optimized:

```
from itertools import groupby

l = ['12.5', '7', '45', '\n', '13.7', '52', '34.3', '\n']

[list(g) for k, g in groupby(lst, '\n'.__eq__) if not k]
# [['12.5', '7', '45'], ['13.7', '52', '34.3']]
```

Or, with float conversion:

```
[list(map(float, g)) for k, g in groupby(lst, '\n'.__eq__) if not k]
# [[12.5, 7.0, 45.0], [13.7, 52.0, 34.3]]
```

Comment: Alternatively, one might also use `pandas` for similar functionality.

Comment: Or `[list(g) for k, g in groupby(lst, '\n'.__eq__) if not k]`

Comment: @Kasramvd Very good point. Updated my answer. Mayby slightly less obvious to the beginner's eye, but definitely worth avoiding the lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Using `numpy`:

```
rows = np.split(z, np.where(arr == '\n')[0] + 1)[:-1]
mat = np.array(rows).astype(np.float)
```

---

Alternatively, if we're sure to be dealing with a *matrix*, you could simply search for the first occurrence of `'\n'`, reshape, and slice using that.

```
first = np.argmax(arr == '\n')
mat = arr.reshape(-1, first + 1)[:, 0:first].astype(np.float)
```

This **might** be faster.

Answer (score 0):

I made a thing for this once upon a time. A [chunking](https://github.com/spyoungtech/chunking) module. It's made to work similar to `str.split`

```
pip install chunking
```

Then

```
>>> from chunking import split
>>> a_list = ["foo", 'bar', 'SEP', 'bacon', 'eggs']
>>> split(a_list, 'SEP')
[['foo', 'bar'], ['bacon', 'eggs']]
```

There's also `chunking.iter_split`, which is a generator variant of that.